# use-package session example please

Tags: use-package, config, session

I want to setup `session` with `use-package` but I don't know elisp except copying from working code. Here is what I've copied:

```el
;;;_* session
(use-package session
  :if (not noninteractive)
  :load-path "site-lisp/session/lisp/"
  :init
  (progn
    (session-initialize)
    (defun remove-session-use-package-from-settings ()
      (when (string= (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) "settings.el")
        (save-excursion
          (goto-char (point-min))
          (when (re-search-forward "^ '(session-use-package " nil t)
            (delete-region (line-beginning-position)
                           (1+ (line-end-position)))))))
    (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings)
    ;; expanded folded secitons as required
    (defun le::maybe-reveal ()
      (when (and (or (memq major-mode  '(org-mode outline-mode))
                     (and (boundp 'outline-minor-mode)
                          outline-minor-mode))
                 (outline-invisible-p))
        (if (eq major-mode 'org-mode)
            (org-reveal)
          (show-subtree))))
    (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook
              'le::maybe-reveal)
    (defun save-information ()
      (with-temp-message "Saving Emacs information..."
        (recentf-cleanup)
        (loop for func in kill-emacs-hook
              unless (memq func '(exit-gnus-on-exit server-force-stop))
              do (funcall func))
        (unless (or noninteractive
                    running-alternate-emacs
                    (eq 'listen (process-status server-process)))
          (server-start))))
    (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information)
    (if window-system
        (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize t))))
```

But I am getting the following error with `--debug-init`:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function session-initialize)
  (session-initialize)
  (progn (session-initialize) (defalias 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings #'(lambda nil (if (string= (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name)) "settings.el") (progn (save-excursion (goto-char ...) (if ... ...)))))) (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings) (defalias 'le::maybe-reveal #'(lambda nil (if (and (or (memq major-mode ...) (and ... outline-minor-mode)) (outline-invisible-p)) (progn (if (eq major-mode ...) (org-reveal) (show-subtree)))))) (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook 'le::maybe-reveal) (defalias 'save-information #'(lambda nil (let ((with-temp-message "Saving Emacs information...") (current-message)) (unwind-protect (progn (if with-temp-message ...) (recentf-cleanup) (let* ... ... nil) (if ... nil ...)) (and with-temp-message (if current-message ... ...)))))) (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information) (if window-system (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize t)))
  (condition-case err (progn (session-initialize) (defalias 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings #'(lambda nil (if (string= (file-name-nondirectory ...) "settings.el") (progn (save-excursion ... ...))))) (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings) (defalias 'le::maybe-reveal #'(lambda nil (if (and (or ... ...) (outline-invisible-p)) (progn (if ... ... ...))))) (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook 'le::maybe-reveal) (defalias 'save-information #'(lambda nil (let ((with-temp-message "Saving Emacs information...") (current-message)) (unwind-protect (progn ... ... ... ...) (and with-temp-message ...))))) (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information) (if window-system (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize t))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :init err)))
  (progn (condition-case err (progn (session-initialize) (defalias 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings #'(lambda nil (if (string= ... "settings.el") (progn ...)))) (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings) (defalias 'le::maybe-reveal #'(lambda nil (if (and ... ...) (progn ...)))) (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook 'le::maybe-reveal) (defalias 'save-information #'(lambda nil (let (... ...) (unwind-protect ... ...)))) (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information) (if window-system (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize t))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :init err))) (if (not (require 'session nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'session) :error)))
  (condition-case err (progn (condition-case err (progn (session-initialize) (defalias 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings #'(lambda nil (if ... ...))) (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings) (defalias 'le::maybe-reveal #'(lambda nil (if ... ...))) (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook 'le::maybe-reveal) (defalias 'save-information #'(lambda nil (let ... ...))) (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information) (if window-system (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize t))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :init err))) (if (not (require 'session nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'session) :error))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :catch err)))
  (progn (defvar use-package--warning10 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg (format "%s/%s: %s" ... keyword ...))) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (progn (condition-case err (progn (session-initialize) (defalias 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings #'(lambda nil ...)) (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings) (defalias 'le::maybe-reveal #'(lambda nil ...)) (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook 'le::maybe-reveal) (defalias 'save-information #'(lambda nil ...)) (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information) (if window-system (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize t))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :init err))) (if (not (require 'session nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'session) :error))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :catch err))))
  (if (not noninteractive) (progn (defvar use-package--warning10 #'(lambda (keyword err) (let ((msg ...)) (display-warning 'use-package msg :error)))) (condition-case err (progn (condition-case err (progn (session-initialize) (defalias 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings #'...) (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'remove-session-use-package-from-settings) (defalias 'le::maybe-reveal #'...) (add-hook 'session-after-jump-to-last-change-hook 'le::maybe-reveal) (defalias 'save-information #'...) (run-with-idle-timer 300 t 'save-information) (if window-system (add-hook ... ... t))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :init err))) (if (not (require 'session nil t)) (display-warning 'use-package (format "Cannot load %s" 'session) :error))) ((debug error) (funcall use-package--warning10 :catch err)))))
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*-868872> nil "/home/...
```

I cannot figure out anything from the above error message.
Somebody give me a working use-package session example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapted from https://github.com/ronert/.emacs.d/blob/master/lisp/init-sessions.el#L29

```el
(use-package session
  :ensure t
  ;:pin melpa-stable
  :config
  (progn
    (setq session-save-file (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/.session"))
    (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'session-initialize)

    ;; save a bunch of variables to the desktop file
    ;; for lists specify the len of the maximal saved data also
    (setq desktop-globals-to-save
          (append '((extended-command-history . 30)
                    (file-name-history        . 100)
                    (grep-history             . 30)
                    (compile-history          . 30)
                    (minibuffer-history       . 50)
                    (query-replace-history    . 60)
                    (read-expression-history  . 60)
                    (regexp-history           . 60)
                    (regexp-search-ring       . 20)
                    (search-ring              . 20)
                    (comint-input-ring        . 50)
                    (shell-command-history    . 50)
                    desktop-missing-file-warning
                    tags-file-name
                    register-alist)))
    ))
```

Tested fine.

Answer (score 1):

`use-package`'s `:init` block is run *before* the package has been loaded. Try putting the code inside a `:config` block instead, like:

```
(use-package session
  :config
  (session-initialize)
  (defun ...
```

I also removed the `progn`, as `use-package` allows multiple statements in the `:config` block.

EDIT: as requested in a comment, the desktop-save-mode use-package block:

```
(use-package desktop
  :ensure nil
  :config
  (desktop-save-mode))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot zck, will it work eventually? The "stack trace" is now gone but I got "Error (use-package): Cannot load session" but nothing else, with --debug-init, or even debug-on-error. Could you post the full use-package session code that works for you please? thx

Comment: Unfortunately, I have never used session. I do use [desktop-save-mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Desktop-Save-Mode.html) to do similar functionality, but not session. You might consider getting session to work outside of use-package first, then moving it into use-package. That might be easier.

Comment: In that case, post your use-package setting with desktop-save-mode please, zck. I just want a working solution to save the state of Emacs from one session to another, but reading the page of https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Desktop-Save-Mode.html gives me no clue how to use it. thx